# Three Mysql Server Replikation (master <-> master <-> master )

Tags: mysql, replication

Three different MySql servers:

`master <-> master <-> master`

Can it be configured as ?
Examples for 2 servers, but I couldn't find examples for 3 servers.

Thanks.

In my tests I was able to run it as `master <-> master` but not as `master <-> master <-> master`.

Comment: Read about [InnoDB Cluster](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-innodb-cluster-introduction.html) or [Percona XtraDB Cluster](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtradb-cluster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3 Masters must be configured in a circle:

```
 M1 -> M2 -> M3 -> M1
```

If any one breaks, you are left with a mess that is very hard to repair.

Don't consider 3 Masters without using InnoDB Cluster or Galera (via MariaDB or Percona).  They have it figured out.

Comment: Good idea, thanks.